# Is it bad style to redefine non-S3 base functions as S3 functions in an R package?

Tags: r, oop

So I'm working on an R package that use S3 classes, and it would be really nice if I could use `sample` as method for one of my classes. However, `base` already declares `sample` as a non-S3 function, so what I wonder is:

**Is it bad style to redefine a non-S3 `base` function such as `sample` as an S3 function? And could this mess things up for users of my package?**

A way you could redefine `sample` and still keep the `base` function working is:

```
sample.default <- base::sample
sample <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod("sample")
}
# This allows me to define a new sample method for my_special_class
sample.my_special_class <- function(...) {...}
```

But what I'm uncertain about is whether this will cause any trouble or namespace issues, for example, when loading other packages. I've also noticed that not many packages redefine `sample`, for example, dplyr uses `sample_n` and igraph uses `sample_`, and I thought that there might be some reason for this...

Comment: If you don't have yet, perhaps you could come up with your own class and define a `sample.yourclassname` to handle your classes. In this way you keep the consistency of using generic functions.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: That doesn't work because `base::sample` isn't generic.  If it were generic, there's no reason to re-define it in your package; you would just register your method.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich bah, you beat me to it. Just checked the functions seconds before your post. You are correct. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884629/turning-an-r-s3-ordinary-function-into-a-generic/41885909#41885909

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whether or not it's bad "style" is primarily opinion-based.  But Writing R Extensions, [Section 7.1 - Adding new generics](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Adding-new-generics) tells you how to add new generics that mask base base/recommended functions.  That said, your proposed solution is explicitly cautioned against in that section:

> ...a package can take over a function in the base package and make it generic by something like
>
> ```
>  foo <- function(object, ...) UseMethod("foo")
>  foo.default <- function(object, ...) base::foo(object)
> ```
>
> Earlier versions of this manual suggested assigning `foo.default <- base::foo`. This is not a good idea, as it captures the base function at the time of installation and it might be changed as R is patched or updated.

One problem others may encounter is if another package also registers `summary` as a generic. Then packages depending on your package or the other package need to decide which generic to register their method with.

Not many packages redefine `sample` because it's usually not a good idea to mask base/recommended functions.  That creates the potential for users to get different behavior at the top-level depending on whether or not your package is loaded.

One thing you certainly want to avoid is masking a generic in a base/recommended (or highly used) package. Doing so can prevent method dispatch at the top-level, causing headaches for users who expect the generic to work (e.g. `dplyr::lag`).

Comment: If I understand the manual correctly, CRAN is suggesting that you define `sample.default <- function(x, ...) base::sample(x, ...)` and considers this permissible.

Comment: @Benjamin why not just make up your own class and extend the generic to handle the class as well?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I believe that's what Rasmus Baath is attempting to do.  The question he is posing is what to do with `base::sample` when he redefines `sample <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("sample")` (please correct me if I'm misunderstanding something)

Comment: @RomanLuštrik by the Law of Large Numbers, it had to happen eventually. :)

Comment: @Benjamin my life strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the link to Writing R Extensions! So since they mention the possibility my take is that it isn't necessary bad style, but could be problematic because it masks generic `sample` in other packages.

Comment: @RasmusBååth: I mentioned that as a possible issue, but it's a fairly small probability.  A package would need to use *both* packages that create the generic *and* want to register a `sample` method.