# Can't fix warning when redefining log as a generic

Tags: r, generics, methods

I would like to make the `log` function a generic so that I can alter it's behavior under some `newclass`.

I have a minimal package with a DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: logmethod
Type: Package
Title: A new Log Method
Version: 0.1
Date: 2017-03-23
Author: Me
Maintainer: Who to complain to <yourfault@somewhere.net>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
License: MIT
LazyData: TRUE
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
```

And the R Code, based on what I've learned at [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Generic-functions-and-methods) and [Is it bad style to redefine non-S3 base functions as S3 functions in an R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236092/is-it-bad-style-to-redefine-non-s3-base-functions-as-s3-functions-in-an-r-packag)

```
#' @name log_method
#' @title A New Log Method
#'
#' @description A new \code{log} method
#'
#' @param x a numeric, complex, or measured variable
#' @param base a positive or complex measured variable: the base with respect to which
#'   logarithms are computed. Defaults to \emph{e}=\code{exp(1)}.
#' @param ... Additional arguments to pass to other methods.
#'
#' @export

log <- function(x, base, ...)
{
  UseMethod("log")
}

#' @rdname log_method
#' @export

log.default <- function(x, base, ...)
{
  base::log(x, base)
}

#' @rdname log_method
#' @export

log.newclass <- function(x, base, ...)
{
  print("See, it dispatched")
  log.default(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(base), ...)
}
```

When I run `check`, I keep getting the warning

> - checking S3 generic/method consistency ... WARNING
>     Warning: declared S3 method 'log.default' not found
>     Warning: declared S3 method 'log.newclass' not found
>     See section 'Generic functions and methods' in the 'Writing R
>     Extensions' manual.

When I install the package, I'm able to use `log.default` and `log.newclass`, so I'm not sure how to interpret this warning that the methods are not found.  [Turning an R S3 ordinary function into a generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41884629/turning-an-r-s3-ordinary-function-into-a-generic/41885909#41885909) describes how to make an S4 function, but I'd like to stick to S3 if possible.  I would love to know why I keep getting this warning.

EDIT:

The NAMESPACE might also be useful.

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

S3method(log,default)
S3method(log,newclass)
export(log)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the piece of the puzzle I was missing is that `log` and most of its cousins are *already* generic.  From the `?log` documentation details

> All except logb are generic functions: methods can be defined for them
>   individually or via the Math group generic.

Thus, the proper coding for the new methods would have been the following (notice the lack of a `UseMethod` call)

```
log.default <- function(x, base, ...)
{
  base::log(x, base)
}

log.newclass <- function(x, base, ...)
{
  print("See, it dispatched")
  log.default(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(base), ...)
}
```

On the other hand, since `logb` is not defined as a generic, that is a case where the instructions in Writing R Extensions would have been relevant (because dispatch is not yet designed)

```
logb <- function(x, base, ...)
{
  UseMethod("logb")
}

logb.default <- function(x, base, ...)
{
  base::logb(x, base)
}

logb.newclass <- function(x, base, ...)
{
  print("See, it dispatched")
  logb.default(as.numeric(x), as.numeric(base), ...)
}
```

So if you're coming across an warning like in the question, it may be worth checking into whether or not the `base` version of the function isn't already a generic.